# How to get XML file from FTP sever to Salesforce..?

Tags: integration

I have an XML file in FTP server, I need to read that file and loaded into document object in salesforce. I have read the below link but I am not able to understand.
**http://www.chiragmehta.info/chirag/2010/03/22/salesforce-ftp-integration-data-loader-web-service-http.**
Can we do an HTTP request to the FTP server..? If yes how I can achieve this without using Third-party tools like jitterbit or skyvia .Can anyone help me to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. Similar question has been asked before -  [How to send and receive data from Salesforce to a FTP server](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57731/how-to-send-and-receive-data-from-salesforce-to-a-ftp-server)

Comment: Please don't post same question multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some middleware that will pull the xml file from the ftp server and pass it back into salesforce.

The request process would look something like: 
Apex -(Rest Request)-> Middleware -(FTP Request)-> File Server -(FTP Response)-> Middleware, then the middleware would upload file into content document via rest api.

> Can we do an HTTP request to the FTP server..?

By definition an FTP server won't respond to HTTP requests.