# Automation that will start as soon as file get drop on client FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, ftp

I am trying to create File drop automation when the file will get drop on client FTP and automation will import that data into Data Extension.

As of now client FTP credential is yet to come, so I made my laptop as a FTP server(one of the folder in my laptop named "FTP_Folder").
After that I added a file location in which I specified Location Type:External FTP site, url:ftp://myIPaddress/Test/, username, port no:21 and password.

I select File Drop as entry source and can see only two folder as Import and Triggered. Unable to see FTP folder, please suggest.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send and receive data from Salesforce to a FTP server](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57731/how-to-send-and-receive-data-from-salesforce-to-a-ftp-server)

Comment: Rather look at this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231558/automation-studio-file-drop-source-from-external-ftp

Comment: Thank you PrzemysławTamoń and  DonL, the way I specified didn't worked so I used the marketing cloud FTP account credentials and directly dropping file on Marketing clod FTP